# How to check status from ResourceProperties object in Azure

Tags: azure, python-3.6

I'm new to Azure. i'm using Blobstorage for storing the files of my project in python  like this.

```
response=block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(settings.CONTAINER_NAME+"/"+"headers",s3_key,file_upload)
```

if i print the response i'm getting the following object.

```
   <azure.storage.blob.models.ResourceProperties object at 0x7fbbd05dbb70>
```

How can i check the status from the response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i check the status from the response object.

The `response` object from `response=block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream` just returns 2 properties: `etag` and `last_modified`. If you want to use these 2 properties, you can easily use `response.etag` or `response.last_modified`.

I debug in visual studio code, and the screenshot as below:

[image]

I think you want to check the status to see if the blob is uploaded completely. If that's the case, you should know that the method `create_blob_from_stream` is **sync method**. Until it completes the uploading, it then returns the response.

I'm using python 3.7 and azure-storage-blob==1.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the definition of `azure.storage.blob.models.ResourceProperties` here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/models.py#L366.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using

```
blob = blob_svc.get_blob_properties(
        container_name=AZURE_CONTAINER,
        blob_name=AZURE_BLOB_NAME)

total_bytes = blob.properties.content_length
print('--> Sent', total_bytes, 'bytes')
```